# onsen-ui Splitview SetSecondaryPage() does not work

Tags: onsen-ui

I setup a splitView using onsen-ui. It works great . When I click the left pane item, it updates the mainpage as expected. However I am trying to update the secondary page by using setSecondaryPage. Nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong??

`<ons-page  style="border-left: 1px solid #ccc" ng-controller="ProvincesCtrl">
    <ul class="topcoat-list" ng-repeat="province in provinces">
        <ons-list-item
            class="topcoat-list__item--tappable topcoat-list__item__line-height" 
            ng-click="ons.splitView.toggle();
            ons.splitView.setSecondaryPage('schools.html');">
            <i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg" style="color: #666"></i>
            &nbsp; {{ province.provinceName }} 
        </ons-list-item>
    </ul>
</ons-page>`

Answer (score 0):

This error has been fixed in latest version of onsen-ui. I used yeoman generator and it downloaded an old version. Lesson learnt is that make sure your generators reference the right libraries. This will avoid you spending hours debugging fixed bugs.